# Problem with static files configurations - don't understand project/app staticfiles organization

Tags: django, static

I have started to develop a Django project with currently 3 apps (registration, monitor and randomization)
I wand to set parameters for statics files.
I am using bootstrap 4.0 and I have currently only one css files for sticky footer
as this css is for all template of the project, I have created a static folder at the project's root:

```
-project
 - settings.py
 - monitor
 - randomization
 - registration
 - static
      - css
         - styles.css
      - images
```

and in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/Users/jl3/DevSpace/intenseTBM_eTool/static/'
```

I have run the commande collectatic but I have an error:

> ERRORS:
>   ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

how can I set 'global' static files for my project?
how should I set parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is pretty clear.

Also, if the STATIC_ROOT is the same as in STATICFILES_DIRS, there is no need to set it in your settings. STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files, in addition to each static folder of each app installed. STATIC_ROOT is the folder where every static files will be stored after a manage.py collectstatic.

Comment: To add to this: You don't need to set `STATIC_ROOT` in your dev environment. In your production environment, you should set `STATIC_ROOT` to a directory **outside** of your project (i.e. not within the source control repository), because this is where `collectstatic` will put all static files, including those from 3rd party packages and Django packages (e.g. django admin site). This is where you'll point nginx/apache to serve your files.

Comment: ok, thanks for replying. I have change like this ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/Users/jl3/DevSpace/static/' ```

Comment: but my styles.css in not applied...[18/Nov/2019 13:58:01] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2377

Comment: Does your css file in the /static/ dirs ? also tried another collectstatic before ?